# how change order of route files defined in RouteServiceProvider - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

As it was presented  [here](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/routing-changes-in-laravel-5-3), I have defined two route files in my `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider`.

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes();
    $this->mapProjectRoutes();

    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    //
}
```

below I have defined

```
protected function mapProjectRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('project/routes/project.php');
    });
}
```

### problem:

I want the routes in `project.php` to be parsed first, then the `web.php`. 
I have checked all four possible positions of the above definitions, e. putting the `mapProjectRoutes` above and below `mapWebRoutes`.
Whatever the order of the functions was, the routes in `web.php` took precedence. 
The only way to make the routes in `project.php` work is to comment out the `$this->mapWebRoutes();`

### my question

How to control the order of the route files.
Just to prevent simple mistakes, after every change of order I was doing `php artisan cache:clear` - didn't help

Thx

Comment: It looks like the issue may have to do with the fact that your project routes also use the web middleware. Is there any reason you separate the project routes other than organization?

Comment: hard to define the answer. One file with routes is published by an external package, my own starter pack. 
For now I changed my project-specific routes' names to avoid conflicts.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I also tried your given codes, and it is not working, I suggest you use modules like `caffeinated/modules` and comment out the routes primary routes maybe this helps.